# Forcing a diferent circuit in TOR

Tags: javascript, ip, tor

I am making tests in a internal site and need to open it using a diferent IP on each try.

I thougth I could do it runing a JS script in a HTML page and open popups using TOR browser, but it always repeats the same IP for the same URL, unless I click in the URL box e select "New Circuit for this site"

There is a way do this using JS?
Or maybe an especific configuration in TOR to force a new circuit to the especific URL?

A very simple example of what I am doing can be see by pasting the code below in a HTML page and refreshing it. In a TOR browser it will show always the same IP unless you click in the padlock near the URL and select to refresh the circuit:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   window.open('http://meuip.com','test', "height=400,width=400,top=500,left=200");
</script>
```

Thanks for the attention e sorry for my poor english

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow _ Ref: "_running a JS script in a HTML page_"; please add the code you tried. Even if it didn't give the result you were expecting, the code could be a starting point for other contributors to assist. Please read how to produce a 'Minimal Reproducible Example' for guidelines >>> https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Edited as sugested 
Thanks!